# Mongo aggregation - passing an array of objects, returning matching record from another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to put together a mongo aggregation, so far without any luck, which will do the following:

1. Take an array of objects, containing multiple fields with 2 key fields (which are "employeeNumber" and "shiftDate").
   e.g.

```
{employeeNumber: '1111', shiftDate: '27/06/2023', name: 'John Doe'}
```

2. Iterate through this array, and find one matching record from another collection, lets call it 'rosters'. In the rosters collection, "employeeNumber" has the same field, but shiftDate is called "workDate".

e.g.

```
{employeeNumber: '1111', workDate: '27/06/2023', name: 'John Doe', startTime: '09:00', endTime: '17:00'}
```

3. Return this one record, and bind/ attach it to the original object, returning a new array of objects with all required data in.
   e.g.

```
{employeeNumber: '1111', shiftDate: '27/06/2023', name: 'John Doe', startTime: '09:00', endTime: '17:00'}
```

Is this possible, and if so can anybody help point me in the right direction?

I know I can do this using a loop but it would be very inefficient.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I tried to put an aggregation together myself using $lookup but didn't get things to work.

The last point I got to with the aggregation was:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "localArray",
      localField: "employeeNumber",
      foreignField: "employeeNumber",
      as: "matchingRecords",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$employeeNumber", "$$employeeNumber"] },
                { $eq: ["$shiftDate", "$$workDate"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      asArray: true
    }
  }
]
```

If anyone can spot what I'm missing that would be amazing.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and indicate which documents should be matched?

Comment: Hi @ray, I've added a similar example for point 2 right now. So as you can see, I'm matching a single record based on the employeeNumber and shiftDate (which is called workDate in the mongo collection). It can only ever possibly match one record from the collection

Comment: Have you tried `$lookup`?

Comment: Hi @Joe, yeah I tried using lookup but couldn't get it to work. I'm pretty new to mongo aggregations. I will edit my post to show the aggregation I tried